# How do I leave the Companions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know if there is a way to leave the Companions, because I want to join the Thieves Guid and take some armor. I killed 4 of their members and all they did was say "I'm getting out of here" or "someone do something".

I just want to leave both guilds without killing them. Is there some quest or mission or something that allows me to leave a guild?

Comment: '*I killed 4 of their members and all they did was say "I'm getting out of here" or "someone do something".*' Are you talking about members of the Thieves Guild, or the Companions?

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to leave the Companions. *Jorrvaskr 4 Life, yo.* You can also go on with both of those guild's questlines while being a member of both guilds.

> I killed 4 of their members and all they did was say "I'm getting out of here" or "someone do something".

Depending on which guild you're talking about, try leaving Riften (Thieves Guild) or Whiterun (the Companions) and wait for at least 48 hours, come back and see if the Thieves Guild or the Companions has calmed down.

You can also try casting the [Calm spells](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pacify_%28effect%29), to calm the panicking guild members.

Answer (score 9):

Dude. Stop for breath. You can join the Thieves Guild as well, I was in both when I played it. There's no way to leave The Companions.

Answer (score 3):

Alan B is right, you cannot leave groups, but you can join multiple groups. The only exceptions are:

- Imperial Legion AND Stormcloaks
- Dawnguard AND Volkihar Clan

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Factions_(Skyrim)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't leave a guild, but there is one way to make them not recognize you!

First leave Whiterun (or whatever city your guild is in), wait 10 hrs, then go back and hit one of the members, after that, run away, leave the city, and repeat until they don't recognize you as a guild member! (I unfortuantly found this out myself by accidentaly stabbing a guild mate!)

Comment: also, I don't recommend joining the thieves guild, since you can never leave them, even if you are a thane, you will always be arrested no matter what :( (its very disappointing, even if all you steal is bread you have to pay a 20G + fine for being in the guild!!!)

Comment: omg we have the same name xD

Comment: Joining the thieves guild does *not* get you arrested.  Murder, Assault, and stealing things in plain sight of a witness, on the other hand, *will* get you arrested.  On the contrary, if you spread the influence of the thieves guild among the other holds, you can "bribe" any guard in those holds who arrests you for incompetence for much less than your bounty value and without getting your loot confiscated.